# Count and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables :

```
exp_channel_titles T (parent table)
exp_category_posts P (many to many table that links to T via column entry_id)
```

I need to know how many entries per category each `author_id` has in P using the `author_id`, `entry_id` fields from T where `T.channel_id = 7`.

e.g.

```
SELECT cat_id, author_id 
FROM exp_channel_titles t, exp_category_posts p
WHERE t.channel_id = 7
AND t.entry_id = p.entry_id
GROUP BY p.cat_id
GROUP BY t.author_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.cat_id, 
    t.author_id,
    count(*) as cat_entries
FROM 
    exp_channel_titles t
    join exp_category_posts p on t.entry_id = p.entry_id
WHERE
    t.channel_id = 7
GROUP BY
    p.cat_id,
    t.author_id
```

Comment: This is good, but note that under certain circumstances, you may need to be a little more careful about what's being counted!

Comment: @Strawberry True, normally I would (and should) qualify the `count(*)` with a table alias similar to `count(t.*)`, but since I wasn't completely sure on which table the information to count was stored, I let the query count based on the grouping.

Comment: actually, you can't count on t.*!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ran the query but I'm getting an empty result set **MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0033 sec )**

Comment: @user1684180 Could you throw some same info in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: I've realized that the query will actually require 3 tables, as the third (exp_channel_data) field_id_19 is the column that holds the reference to the entry_id that is required to get the cat_id. Hmm, this will be a lot more complicated that originally thought. I've created the schema, I haven't used that tool before. It doesn't have any data though. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8491/1

Comment: Just looking at what you have there, you really need to consider reworking the exp_channel_data table, are all of those needed? would they be better suited else where? Better field names is a must.